# Selecting values from data frame

Tags: r

I Want to select a value from the data frame which is greater than the specified value. my data frame consist of single column only

I'm trying `which.max` function but that only returns the first value of the data frame

`d[which.max(d$slope > 14.9),]`

I want a single value. very first one greater than the specified

Comment: Or `d$slope[d$slope > n][1]`

Comment: still same results. it select very first value of the data frame

Comment: Yes the very first value greater than your specified value...Isn't this what you want??

Comment: No. Regardless of value it only returns very first value.

Comment: Oh, ok...you need to order first...something like `v1 <- sort(d$slope); v1[v1 > n][1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your dataframe by slope then use `Position` to have the first match:

```
dd <- d[order(d$slope), , drop = FALSE]
dd$slope[Position(function(x) x > 14.9, dd$slope)]
```

`Position` evaluates until the first `TRUE` condition only. It should be much faster than using `which` or a full vector comparison.

Or you can use `which.min` to get the lower value that is greater than your threshold:

```
d[d$slope > 14.9][which.min(d$slope[d$slope > 14.9]),]
```

Comment: *"It should be much faster than using which or a full vector comparison."* Interesting (+1). Now I'm curious to see a `microbenchmark`...

Comment: @MauritsEvers I just checked the code, it is a for loop stopping at first match. `for` loops are quite slow in `R`. Speed depends on the position of the first match and vector length I guess.

Comment: Still returning the same first value

Comment: here is my data frame

structure(list(slope = c(48.2842712474617, -3.70868881301709, 
12.1029479318971, 9.36316340309529, -3.94080481597174, 0.598807829449678
)), .Names = "slope", row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

I want to select a value greater than the specified value. let say if we specify 14.9, I want 15 or something like this

Comment: that's what I'm getting even if I change ```14.9 ``` to ``` 1.9 ```.  ```48.28``` is the very first value . I've 150 values in data frame

Comment: @NaumanKhalid 48.28 is also the first value greater than 1.9 in the dataframe. Do you want the first value above the threshold ? `dd <- d[order(d$slope), , drop = FALSE];
dd$slope[Position(function(x) x > 14.9, dd$slope)]`